# Extract all the data from Android - Galaxy J5 (J500FN) Failure: Custom binary blocked by FAP

Tags: android, root, recovery, data-extraction, samsung-galaxy

I **rooted** my **Android J500FN** and after deactivating (didn't know that i shouldn't) **OEM-Unlock**, I got **Custom binary blocked by FAP**.

Is there a way to extract all my data before to flash new Android OS?

Comment: Is wiping (flash new OS ) the only way to fix this? Coz i can't wipe as I have important data on the internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

Install stock ROM using Odin and check options, It doesn't wipe data and you can then use it with all your data intact.